# How to pass a php while result variable to include.php located inside the bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop

I want pass a variable from php while to include.php inside the bootstrap modal.
My php while is  on the whileresult.php

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $rows) {
        $title_books=mysql_result($result,$i,"title_books");
        $pages_books=mysql_result($result,$i,"pages_books");
        $author_books=mysql_result($result,$i,"author_books");
?>
<?php echo $title_books; ?>
```

after, there is a bootstrap modal and this there are a include.php

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShareBk">Book in library</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- start modal with include.php -->
<div id="modalShareBk" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Your Books</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php include("include.php"); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, how to pass the value of variable $title_books inside the include.php page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply echo out the values in the include file the scope of the variable will be there in include.php

PS. Use require_once() instead of include()

Edit 1:
You need to change the whileresult.php code to something like this

**whileresult.php**

```
<?php
$i=0;
$title_books = array();
$pages_books = array();
$author_books = array();
while ($i < $rows) {
    $title_books[$i]=mysql_result($result,$i,"title_books");
    $pages_books[$i]=mysql_result($result,$i,"pages_books");
    $author_books[$i]=mysql_result($result,$i,"author_books");
    $i++;
?>
```

**include.php**

```
<?php
for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++)
{
   echo 'Book - '.$title_books[$j].' Pages - '.$pages_books[$j].'Author - '.$author_books[$j];
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry but I not understand. Can you post an example?

Comment: If write <?php echo $title_books; ?> inside the include.php file, print always the first result of while result.

Comment: There is a problem. In whileresult.php page, the first while result in my post are print inside <li><?php echo $book_title; ?></li> With your solution, the build page whileresult.php have a some array errors.

Comment: You need to initialise those array first above while loop like $title_books = array();

Comment: If you need to print first result then you can print like <?php echo $title_books[0]; ?>

Comment: Hope now this helps.